# Load page that has html/js with AJAX

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to load a php page with AJAX. The issue is that it has a "share this" button inside that uses a Javascript script being loaded in that same page.

When I load the page with AJAX, the "share this" button does not display correctly since the Javascript inside is not being loaded.

Any ideas on how I can make the Javascript in the page load?

Thanks,
Alain

P.S. - I'm using jQuery for javascript

UPDATE:

I still cannot get it to work. Here is the html/js I'm trying to load:

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a href="http://www.addthis.com/bookmark.php?v=250&amp;username=leblon" class="addthis_button_compact" addthis:url="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" addthis:title="<?php the_title(); ?>">Share
<span class="at300bs at15t_compact"></span>
</a>
<span class="addthis_separator">|</span>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_1"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_2"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_3"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_preferred_4"></a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#username=leblon" id="the-script"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

Here is a snippet of my javascript file:

```
$.ajax({ url: theURL + link+'/?from=us', success: function(html){
  $('#drink').html(html);
}
```

Anyone?

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT/REDO:

*Registered with AddThis, and it seems that its implemented a little different than yours.*

#### HTML TO BE LOADED

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'xxx-xxx-xx-xx-xx'});</script>

<span class="st_twitter_large" displayText="Tweet">
</span><span class="st_facebook_large" displayText="Facebook"></span>
<span class="st_ybuzz_large" displayText="Yahoo! Buzz"></span>
<span class="st_gbuzz_large" displayText="Google Buzz"></span>
<span class="st_email_large" displayText="Email"></span>
<span class="st_sharethis_large" displayText="ShareThis"></span>
```

#### AJAX SIDE (Loading other page)

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script tyle="text/javascript">
 var addthis_config = {"data_track_clickback":true};
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({ url:'test.php', success: function(html){
    $('#content').html(html);

}});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content" style="width:400px;border:1px solid black;height:300px;margin:auto"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**You may have an older version and the buttons were not being init() upon execution ajax side.**

Comment: I still cannot get it to work. Updated my question. I also tried loading the script manually with JS.. (and I saw it being loaded through Firebug... but it wouldn't do its magic)

Comment: So I signed up for addThis, and did exactly what you want, with no issues. It seems to me that you are using an older version of addThis?

Comment: What i did here works, you may need to update your addthis, and use the newer api, mine says "Publisher" rather than "username" which Im not sure makes a difference. Give it a try tho.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you're adding the content of the page into your current page.

Something like this should work:

```
$.get('/path/to/new/page', function(data){
    $('#someDiv').html(data);
});
```

If that's not working, then the script tags in the pulled page aren't properly being interpreted.  I believe I ran into this issue a while back, bypassing jQuery may help: `$('#someDiv')[0].innerHTML = data`, or if that doesn't work you're next step is to use a regex to pull the script tags, manually download and eval those.

Comment: innerHTML has problems evaluating script tags in IE, so you can't rely on that. jQuery does things to workaround this issue (creating document fragments, etc.)

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the AJAX onComplete/success event, once triggered call your js function targeting the share button.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "YourPage.php",
  context: document.body,
  success: function(){
    //Call Share Button function
  }
});
```

And note if there is custom events on your button to use the .live bind method instead of the normal event handlers. (.live handles dynamic content)